# Is it possible to implement HTML5 (I plan to use WebRTC)as a WebView within a native Android application?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, webrtc

I am thinking about developing a android application to make a WebRTC call. Unfortunately the native WebView in android does not support such feature. I tried XDK with CrossWalk and it works with WebRTC well, but the problem is that it is a pure HTML, Javascript application. I suppose the capability of HTML5 application in android would be a problem? (Notification, service, communication with database). So what I am thinking is that maybe I can build a hybrid application with the framework of a native application and a WebView with it? Thanks in advance, that would help me a lot.

Comment: yes, you can use webRTC with in webView for native applications. Please have a look at the link https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#does_the_new_webview_have_feature_parity_with_chrome_for_android_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I build this HTML5 , https://www.noupei.com/. Its fully HTML5, build using jQuery and jQuery Mobile. One of my college easily transpose it using a webview for android, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.knowledge7.android.noupei

BUT

It is also possible to completely develop your whole application using HTML5, and then package it with something like [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/), the advantage you have is that using something like phonegap allows you to access the native features of the Android Device.

For HTML5 technologies like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) that allows you to make very good mobile interfaces are fully mobile responsive. It is possible to make very beautiful and attractive interfaces as well as you also have very good javascript frameworks like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your rely! I checked the webview in phonegap for android and it support most HTML5 features but WebRTC is not among them. I suppose the CrossWalk is the only solution...thanks anyway